# Passing fscanf / sscanf string into a structure field char[4]

Tags: c, struct, scanf

How the two struct field definitions below differentiate from each other.

```
//first struct    
typedef struct{
    char *name;  //here is the difference
    int shares;
} STOCK1;


//second struct
typedef struct{
    char name[4];  //here is the difference
    int shares;
} STOCK2;


//here inside main()
FILE *fpRead = openFile(input_filename, "r");

STOCK1 s1; 
fscanf(fpRead, "%s %d", s1.name, &s1.shares);
printf("%s %d ", s1.name, s1.shares);

STOCK2 s2;
fscanf(fpRead, "%s %d", s2.name, &s2.shares);
printf("%s %d ", s2.name, s2.shares);
```

The code will print out:

```
MSFT 400
MSFT� 400
```

As you can see using second struct, it will print some garbage character after string. Why is that?

input string:

```
MSFT 400
YHOO 100
...
```

Comment: `char name[4];` --> `char name[5];` or more. Also You need allocate for `s1.name` before use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the 2 `struct` definitions is that you are pre-allocating storage in one `struct` and declaring a pointer in the other `struct`.

In your first `struct`, you have `char *`. `char *` is a pointer. It is not pointing to anything. You need to dynamically allocate some memory, then point your `char *` pointer to that allocated memory.

In your second `struct`, you have `char name[4]`. This is an array and you are allocated 4 bytes to this array. This is allocated and ready to be used.

Use the first `struct` if you do not know the size of the buffer in advance. Allocate an arbitrary amount of memory, such as 1024 bytes, using `malloc`. Then read in 1024 bytes of data in at a time. Keep doing this until you can calculate how big the data is total, then use `malloc` to allocate that amount of memory, then read in your data.

Use the second `struct` if you know that your data is always 4 bytes long and it will never by bigger or smaller than that. If you want, you can declare it like this: `char name[500]`. This will pre-allocate 500 bytes for you and as long as your string isn't bigger than 499 characters, this will work. However, you could be wasting memory (which isn't a big deal these days). The most efficient way to conquer this problem is to dynamically allocate the amount of memory you actually need using `malloc`

One last warning....Remember that strings in C need enough memory for the string itself, plus a null terminator. For example:

```
/* I am allocating 5 bytes to store my name. 
   My name is Alan, so I'm allocating 4 bytes
   plus 1 additional byte for the null terminator
*/

char myName[5];
myName[0] = 'A';  // A
myName[1] = 'l';  // l
myName[2] = 'a';  // a
myName[3] = 'n';  // n
myName[4] = '\0'; // Null Terminator

printf("%s", myName); // Prints Alan
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of `STOCK2.name` is 4 characters. Your string has this 4 characters + the terminator character `\0`. This are 5 characters. So the terminator is behind the structure component overlapping the `shares` component. If you set the `shares` component, it overwrites the string terminator.

Let's have an example layout to illustrate this (32-Bit/4-byte integers). After writing the name:

```
n+0 name[0] M
n+1 name[1] S
n+2 name[2] F
n+3 name[3] T
n+4 shares  \0 <- terminator
n+5 shares
n+6 shares
n+7 shares

n+0 name[0] M
n+1 name[1] S
n+2 name[2] F
n+3 name[3] T
n+4 shares  144 | Example for 400 stored in a 32-bit int (144+1*256)
n+5 shares  1   |
n+6 shares  0   |
n+7 shares  0   |
```

The terminator is gone and `printf()` continues writing out characters after the T.

To solve this issue, resize the name component.

BTW: Having a unlimited read from a file makes it possible to attack your software with a buffer overflow.